# Free fortran compiler with GUI for mac OS X

Tags: macos, user-interface, fortran

i need a fortran compiler for mac OSX (Mountain Lion), but I haven't found anything with a GUI. Do you know a free fortran compiler with a user interface to run my scripts?

Thank you

Comment: Try gfortran (MacPorts `gcc48`) and [Eclipse/Photran](http://www.eclipse.org/photran/).

Comment: Try gfortran and Emacs, but your question is off-topic here.

Comment: Or gfortran and [geany](http://wiki.geany.org/howtos/osx/running)

Comment: I vote for [vim](http://www.vim.org/)! It has an excellent Fortran support...

Comment: @AlexanderVogt: one man (I presume), two votes, not fair.  Be honest, the neat trim well-honed Vim or the bloated, unreliable, behemoth that Eclipse+Photran has become.  You, and anyone else, can reliably infer my preferences ...

Comment: (@HighPerformanceMark: To be honest I never used Photran, I just assumed it would be best for a beginner...)

Comment: I'm a bit confused: are you looking for an IDE or a GUI interface that works wit Fortran i.e. something that draws circles, buttons, graphs etc.

Comment: @cup you're right! i was looking for something like Geany! Thank you all for your help. :) and thank you cup to adjust my bull****

Comment: There are loads: depends on what you are looking for and what you're used to.  In addition to the ones already mentioned, there is also kdevelop, absoft, codelite, codeblocks and simply.  Some like eclipse are a bit quirky.